# Como eu posso fazer pra rodar Harbour no Apache?

Tags: apache, harbour

Para algumas linguagens funcionarem no Apache, como PERL ou PHP, podemos instalar o `mod_perl` ou o `mod_php`. No PHP ainda temos a opção do PHP FPM. Já no caso do Python, podemos usar WSGI.

E no caso do Harbour? Eu gostaria de saber se tem como rodar a linguagem (Harbour) no Apache, fazendo com que os arquivos `.prg` interpretados.

Exemplo:

```
PROCEDURE Main()

   ? "<div>Hello HTML</div>"

   RETURN
```

Comment: Existem umas iniciativas nesse sentido, mas já adianto: a maior parte delas parece piada de mau gosto. Lembrando ainda que se quiser, pode muito bem pular a parte do Apache e fazer o servidor todo já em Harbour, se for para alguma atividade mais específica (claro, o Apache ja é especializado nisso, reimplementar inteiro provavelmente é besteira, mas em geral as aplicações tem finalidade específica, então talvez compense um "servidor específico" para a tarefa também).

Comment: @Bacco eu li alguma coisa a respeito de `mod_harbour` para o Apache. Você acha que compensa?

Comment: Se for o que eu tou pensando, compensa ficar longe kkk (mas acho que não cabe essa discussão aqui, aí já começa um juizo de valor que precisa de fundamentação, e ficaria extenso e fora do objetivo do post e do próprio site).